# How to load text from a file using requirejs text plugin in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, requirejs

In my chrome extension I want to load html stored inside a file named `fontOptions.html`.
To do that I am using text plugin for requirejs.
I am using `background` script and not `content_script`

Here are my files.
`manifest.json`:

```
{
    ....
        "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
        },
    ....
}
```

`background.js`:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    // Add all the libraries one by one through callback using programmatic injection
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        file: 'thirdParty/jquery-2.0.3.js'
    }, function () {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
            file: 'thirdParty/require.js'
        }, function () {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
                file: 'thirdParty/text.js'
            }, function () {
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
                    file: 'thirdParty/mustache.js'
                }, function () {
                    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
                        file: 'print.js'
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

`print.js`:

```
......
// Testing requirejs's text pugin
    require(["text!fontOptions.html"], function(fontText){
    console.log('fontText = ' + fontText);
});
......
```

`fontOptions.html`:  (The text inside this file will be changed later to the proper html code)

```
This is the html file for font options
```

My problem is when I run the extension it gives me this error.

```
Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: [object Object]
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch                     require.js:166
makeError                                                          require.js:166
intakeDefines                                                     require.js:1221
localRequire                                                      require.js:1402
requirejs                                                         require.js:1737
(anonymous function)                                                  print.js:54
```

What am I doing wrong here ?